# How to log the line number of the error when catching a chrome.runtime.lastError?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm catching the async errors from my code via

```
if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError)
    notify({m:chrome.runtime.lastError.message},'error')
}
```

but this only gives the message in the Chrome Dev Tools.  This happens a lot and makes me lose a lot of time tracing back the error. Is there any way to catch the line number of the original error?   I've debugged the object chrome.runtime.lastError, but there are some protected properties I cannot access, though it might not be what I'm looking for (caller, Scopes)

Comment: It should be possible to capture the error stack using `new Error().stack`, look for existing answers.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out. Do you also know if it cannot be get from ´chrome.runtime.lastError´ or other properties under ´chrome.runtime´ ?

Comment: It's not in the documentation so I don't think so.